# xv6 lab network: encounter a problem after swapping two lines of code

Tags: xv6

I am working on the xv6 lab of network. My job  is to finish `e1000_transmit()` and `e1000_recv()` in driver code for E1000 so that the driver can transmit and receive packets.

Here is the basic introduction to this lab: https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.S081/2023/labs/net.html

The code will be executed on qemu-system-riscv64. I found when I swap `net_rx()` and `regs[E1000_RDT] = cur;` in `e1000_recv()`,  xv6 doesn't receive UDP packet from the host.

Here is my correct version of `e1000_recv()`(I did't follow the introduction hints completely).

```
void
e1000_recv(void)
{
  //
  // Your code here.
  //
  // Check for packets that have arrived from the e1000
  // Create and deliver an mbuf for each packet (using net_rx()).
  //
  //printf("RX\n");

  struct mbuf *tmp = 0;
  uint32 rdh = 0;
  uint32 rdt = 0;
  uint32 cur = 0;
  do
  {
    rdh = regs[E1000_RDH];
    rdt = regs[E1000_RDT];
    cur = (rdt + 1) % RX_RING_SIZE;

    //printf("rx rdh:%d rdt:%d cur:%d\n", rdh, rdt, cur);

    if (cur == rdh)
    {
      break;
    }

    if ((rx_ring[cur].status & E1000_RXD_STAT_DD) == 0)
    {
      return;
    }

    tmp = mbufalloc(0);
    if (tmp == 0)
    {
      printf("rx error\n");
    }

    tmp->head = tmp->buf;
    tmp->len = rx_ring[cur].length;
    tmp->next = rx_mbufs[cur]->next;
    memmove(tmp->head, (void *)rx_ring[cur].addr, rx_ring[cur].length);
    rx_ring[cur].status = 0;
    rx_ring[cur].length = 0;
    rx_ring[cur].csum = 0;
    rx_ring[cur].errors = 0;
    rx_ring[cur].special = 0;
    net_rx(tmp);
    regs[E1000_RDT] = cur;
    
  } while (cur != rdh);
}
```

`regs[E1000_RDT] = cur;`  is after `net_rx()`, it's okay when we use `make grade` (CPU core number is three). `make grade` will run `nettests` that includes trasmitting and receiving packets tests. But here we focus on the first test that is only a process in xv6 system is transmitting and listening.

Here is the tcpdump result.

```
reading from file packets.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 65536
01:09:30.363741 IP 10.0.2.15.2000 > 10.0.2.2.26099: UDP, length 19
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 5254 0012 3456 0800 4500  ......RT..4V..E.
        0x0010:  002f 0000 0000 6411 3eae 0a00 020f 0a00  ./....d.>.......
        0x0020:  0202 07d0 65f3 001b 0000 6120 6d65 7373  ....e.....a.mess
        0x0030:  6167 6520 6672 6f6d 2078 7636 21         age.from.xv6!
01:09:30.363915 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.2.15 tell 10.0.2.2, length 46
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 5255 0a00 0202 0806 0001  ......RU........
        0x0010:  0800 0604 0001 5255 0a00 0202 0a00 0202  ......RU........
        0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0a00 020f 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000            ............
01:09:31.316558 ARP, Reply 10.0.2.15 is-at 52:54:00:12:34:56, length 28
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 5254 0012 3456 0806 0001  ......RT..4V....
        0x0010:  0800 0604 0002 5254 0012 3456 0a00 020f  ......RT..4V....
        0x0020:  5255 0a00 0202 0a00 0202                 RU........
01:09:31.316716 IP 10.0.2.2.26099 > 10.0.2.15.2000: UDP, length 17
        0x0000:  5254 0012 3456 5255 0a00 0202 0800 4500  RT..4VRU......E.
        0x0010:  002d 0000 0000 4011 62b0 0a00 0202 0a00  .-....@.b.......
        0x0020:  020f 65f3 07d0 0019 3216 7468 6973 2069  ..e.....2.this.i
        0x0030:  7320 7468 6520 686f 7374 2100            s.the.host!.
01:09:31.321030 IP 10.0.2.15.2000 > 10.0.2.2.26099: UDP, length 19
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 5254 0012 3456 0800 4500  ......RT..4V..E.
        0x0010:  002f 0000 0000 6411 3eae 0a00 020f 0a00  ./....d.>.......
        0x0020:  0202 07d0 65f3 001b 0000 6120 6d65 7373  ....e.....a.mess
        0x0030:  6167 6520 6672 6f6d 2078 7636 21         age.from.xv6!
...
...
```

And after swapping the above two lines. xv6 can't receive the UDP packet(the swapping won't cause problems in logic). Below is the result of tcpdump.

```
reading from file packets.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 65536
01:22:28.362597 IP 10.0.2.15.2000 > 10.0.2.2.26099: UDP, length 19
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 5254 0012 3456 0800 4500  ......RT..4V..E.
        0x0010:  002f 0000 0000 6411 3eae 0a00 020f 0a00  ./....d.>.......
        0x0020:  0202 07d0 65f3 001b 0000 6120 6d65 7373  ....e.....a.mess
        0x0030:  6167 6520 6672 6f6d 2078 7636 21         age.from.xv6!
01:22:28.362785 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.2.15 tell 10.0.2.2, length 46
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 5255 0a00 0202 0806 0001  ......RU........
        0x0010:  0800 0604 0001 5255 0a00 0202 0a00 0202  ......RU........
        0x0020:  0000 0000 0000 0a00 020f 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000            ............
01:22:29.316720 ARP, Reply 10.0.2.15 is-at 52:54:00:12:34:56, length 28
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 5254 0012 3456 0806 0001  ......RT..4V....
        0x0010:  0800 0604 0002 5254 0012 3456 0a00 020f  ......RT..4V....
        0x0020:  5255 0a00 0202 0a00 0202                 RU........
```

Also, when I use `make qemu`, `make server` and `nettests` instead of `make grade`(It uses python script to execute `make qemu`, `make server` and `nettests`) the tests can pass. And when I change CPUS from 3 to 1,  `make grade` can also pass. It's weird.

The net lab introduction gives some hints that we should put `regs[E1000_RDT] = cur;` at the end.But I want to know the reason why my change have above problems. I have read the E1000 hareware manul, and I can't find any explanation.